# Fail to use a substring to print out part of a sentence

Tags: java, loops, substring

The basic algorithm  is I have an input file which has number of sentences, each sentence is on each line.I want to print out part of a sentence from position s to e but with this code below, it prints out blank lines.Can someone show me where my mistakes is?

```
public class Email13 
{
    static boolean isValidEmailCharacter(char c)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if((c>='A'&&c<='Z')||(c>='a'&&c<='z')||(c>='0'&&c<='9')||(c=='.')||(c=='-')||(c=='+'))
            result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader cin, fin;
        cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //Description
        System.out.println("Programmer: Minh Nguyen");
        System.out.println("Description: This program is to start the final project.");
        System.out.println();    

        String nameIn, nameOut, deIn, deOut;
        nameIn="";
        nameOut="";
        deIn = "fileContainingEmails.txt";

        System.out.print("Enter input filename [default:" + deIn + "]: ");
        nameIn = cin.readLine();

        if(nameIn.compareTo("")==0){
            nameIn = deIn;
            deOut = "copyPasteMyEmails.txt";
            System.out.print("Enter output filename [default:" + deOut + "]: ");
            nameOut = cin.readLine();
            if(nameOut.compareTo("")==0)
                nameOut = deOut;
        }
        else if(nameIn.compareTo("")>0){
            deOut = nameIn;
            System.out.print("Enter output filename [default:" + deOut + "]: ");
            nameOut = cin.readLine();
            if(nameOut.compareTo("")==0)
                nameOut = nameIn;
        }
        fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameIn));
        //Read the input file
        while(true)
        {
            if(!fin.ready()) break;
            String lineFromFile;
            lineFromFile = fin.readLine();
            int s, e, hasDot;

            for (int i = 0; i < lineFromFile.length(); i++) // for each char in the string...           
            {
                if(lineFromFile.charAt(i)=='@')
                {
                    for(s=i;s>-1;s--)
                    {
                        if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(s))==false)
                            break;
                    }
                    for(e=i; e< lineFromFile.length(); e++)
                    {
                        if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(e))==false)
                            break;
                    }

                    String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s,e);
                    System.out.println(anEmail);
                }                                             
            }
        }
        fin.close();

        PrintWriter fout;
        fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(nameOut));
        fout.close();        
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't recognize the positions s & e;

Answer (score 0):

when you do s--, if all your characters are good, that for loop could finish with s equal to -1. Same issue could effect e++. but with the last index of a substring you want to be one more than the char position. i.e. String cat = "Cat"; String temp = cat.substring(0, 1) returns C.

For your s loop to check the boundary try:

```
for(s=i;s>-1;s--)
{
if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(s))==false)
break; 
}
if(s <0)// if it never hit break s is now == -1
s=0;
```

just keep in mind the basics of loops. if i do

```
for(a=0; a<10; a++)
;
```

a is equal to 10 when i'm done. it doesn't execute the loop on value 10 because by being 10 it fails a< 10,  but it does finish with a=10.

Comment: I just added these code before the loop: else s=0 and else e=lineFromLine(); but it keeps printing nothing:(

Comment: seems what you want for boundary checking is after the loop, is s < = then set s to 0. the end index is exclusive i.e. from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int) you can go one more than the char position your after.

Comment: this is designed to get something to print you may still have to do some work on the boundary.  Main thing to try is make sure s is not -1 when you use substring as far as i can tell as to things that will cause an error with the substring call.

Comment: But i use s>-1 as a condition so 0 is the maximum value it can reach.

Comment: if you think about it, it has to set s to a value that fails, i.e. -1 before it can fail, then you use that value after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I try this but it doesn't work:(           
      s=i;
  while(s>-1)
  {
      if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(s))==false)
        break;
      else
          s = 0;
      s--;
  }
  e=i;
  while(e< lineFromFile.length())
  {
      if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(e))==false)
      break;
      else
          e = lineFromFile.length();
      e++;`enter code here`
  }
```

Comment: i edited my post a bit. see if you can get my point i'm making, i cant guarantee it solves all your problems but it is one issue i see.

Comment: also this solution is probably worse because even if you did want to set s to 0 there, and i don't think you want to, the next line does s--- so your back at negative 1.